# how to set required data with RealmRecyclerViewAdapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, realm

> i want to set required user(view ) but it shows all the data

**note:**  invite is the default text for button

**explanation**

> 1. list has 50 contacts. And 5 of them are registered +followed by loggedIn contact And other 5 them are only registered And remaining 40 contacts  so i want to show only followed + registered contacts it means only 10 contacts wanna set to recyclerviews
>
> So, i m facing the issue is it show all 50 contacts to the recyclerview

**code**

public class FollowAdapter extends RealmRecyclerViewAdapter{

```
private Realm realm;
private Context context;
private ActionListener actionListener;
private InviteListener inviteListener;
private String TAG = getClass().getName();

public void setActionListener(ActionListener actionListener) {
    this.actionListener = actionListener;
}

public void setInviteListener(InviteListener inviteListener) {
    this.inviteListener = inviteListener;
}


public FollowAdapter(Context context, Realm realm, OrderedRealmCollection<ContactClass> airports) {
    super(context, airports, true);
    this.realm = realm;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.follow_item, parent, false);
    Holder holder = new Holder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final ContactClass contactClass = getData().get(position);
    Holder mHolder = (Holder) holder;

    if (contactClass.getIsRegister() != null && contactClass.getIsRegister() && contactClass.getIsFollow() != null && contactClass.getIsFollow()) {
        mHolder.follow.setText(context.getString(R.string.unfollow));
        mHolder.contactName.setText(contactClass.getName());
        mHolder.contactNumber.setText(contactClass.getNumber());
        Drawable drawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(holder.itemView.getContext().getResources(), R.drawable.camera, null);
        if (!contactClass.getAvatar().equals("") && contactClass.getAvatar() != null) {
            Glide.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(contactClass.getAvatar()).into(mHolder.contact_pic).onLoadFailed(drawable);
        } else {
            int color = holder.itemView.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.universal);
            ColorFilter cf = new PorterDuffColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
            mHolder.contact_pic.setColorFilter(cf);
            // Drawable mDefaultBackground = holder.itemView.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.app_icon);
            mHolder.contact_pic.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        }

    } else if (contactClass.getIsFollow() != null && !contactClass.getIsFollow() && contactClass.getIsRegister() != null && contactClass.getIsRegister()) {
        mHolder.follow.setText(context.getString(R.string.follow));
        mHolder.contactName.setText(contactClass.getName());
        mHolder.contactNumber.setText(contactClass.getNumber());
        Drawable drawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(holder.itemView.getContext().getResources(), R.drawable.camera, null);
        if (!contactClass.getAvatar().equals("") && contactClass.getAvatar() != null) {
            Glide.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(contactClass.getAvatar()).into(mHolder.contact_pic).onLoadFailed(drawable);
        } else {
            int color = holder.itemView.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.universal);
            ColorFilter cf = new PorterDuffColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
            mHolder.contact_pic.setColorFilter(cf);
            // Drawable mDefaultBackground = holder.itemView.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.app_icon);
            mHolder.contact_pic.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        }
    }



}


}

private class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView contact_pic;
    TextView contactName, contactNumber;
    AppCompatButton follow;

    public Holder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        contact_pic = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contact_pic);
        contactName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contact_name);
        contactNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contact_number);
        follow = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_follow);
        contactName.setSelected(true);
        contactNumber.setSelected(true);
    }
}



public interface ActionListener {
    void actionListener(Boolean action, User user);

}

public interface InviteListener {
    void inviteListener(String phone);

}
```

}

> u can see above code i only set registered+followed(that 5 contacts) And registered five contacts **But the problem Is** it sets All the 50 contacts .

**setting up data to adapter**

```
Realm realm1 = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        RealmResults<ContactClass> realmResults = realm1.where(ContactClass.class).findAllAsync();
        followAdapter = new FollowAdapter(getApplicationContext(), realm1, realmResults);
        recyclerview_followed.setAdapter(followAdapter);
```

**contactClass.class**

```
public class ContactClass extends RealmObject implements Serializable {
    String id;
    String name;
    @PrimaryKey
    String number;
    String avatar;
    double followers;
    double Followings;
    Boolean isRegister;
    Boolean isFollow;

    public Boolean getIsRegister() {
        return isRegister;
    }

    public void setIsRegister(Boolean register) {
        isRegister = register;
    }

    public Boolean getIsFollow() {
        return isFollow;
    }

    public void setIsFollow(Boolean follow) {
        isFollow = follow;
    }

    public double getFollowers() {
        return followers;
    }

    public void setFollowers(double followers) {
        this.followers = followers;
    }

    public double getFollowings() {
        return Followings;
    }

    public void setFollowings(double followings) {
        Followings = followings;
    }


    public String getAvatar() {
        return avatar;
    }

    public void setAvatar(String avatar) {
        this.avatar = avatar;
    }


    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }


    public ContactClass() {
    }


    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
```

[image: result i got]

**updated realm filter**

```
 RealmResults<ContactClass> realmResults = realm1.where(ContactClass.class).equalTo("isRegister", true).equalTo("isFollow", true).findAllAsync();
```

> above code will give all isRegister=true,isFollow=true so i m able to set all users followed user ans set text to unfollow But i also want  isRegister=true,isFollow=false users an want to set text to follow  for which i tried below filter but got result nothing.

```
RealmResults<ContactClass> realmResults = realm1.where(ContactClass.class).equalTo("isRegister", true).equalTo("isFollow", true).equalTo("isRegister", false).findAllAsync();
```

Comment: Well you **are** using `findAllAsync()` with no additional conditions, so of course you'll receive all of them. So what is `ContactClass`?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce  it is pojo class i have updated que with ContactClass  and see i have added filters that i have tried but still im stuck and little bit far from expected result can u help me?

Comment: later on also tried this but i only got isFollow=true and isRegister=false not isFollow=flase and IsRegister=true 
**RealmResults<ContactClass> realmResults = realm1.where(ContactClass.class).beginGroup().equalTo("isRegister", false).or().equalTo("isRegister", true).endGroup().equalTo("isFollow", true).findAllAsync();**

Comment: You literally just need `RealmResults<ContactClass> realmResults = realm1.where(ContactClass.class).equalTo("isRegister", true).findAllAsync();`  then

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for

```
RealmResults<ContactClass> realmResults = 
    realm.where(ContactClass.class)
         .equalTo("isRegister",  true)
         .findAllAsync();
```

You might want to use `findAllSortedAsync()` by property though for consistent collection change.

Comment: actually i solved it few days ago but  u still didn't get my question ... my question was to get (isRegister=true ,isRegister=fasle and isFollow=true)  so i use or() method of Realm to get both isRegister=true ,isRegister=flase ...

Answer (score 0):

To fetch only regsitered users list you need to update your query with following:

```
RealmResults<ContactClass> realmResults = realm.where(ContactClass.class).equalTo("isRegister", true).findAllAsync();
```

for this:

> above code will give all isRegister=true,isFollow=true so i m able to
>   set all users followed user ans set text to unfollow But i also want
>   isRegister=true,isFollow=false users an want to set text to follow for
>   which i tried below filter but got result nothing.

Use this:

```
RealmResults<ContactClass> realmResults = realm1.where(ContactClass.class).equalTo("isRegister", true).equalTo("isFollow", false).findAllAsync();
```

Let me know, does this helps you.